# Code in link function not executing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a directive (kind of new to Angular and plunker) and the code I'm placing in the `link` function isn't executing at all. I simplified it down to just a console.log statement but it doesn't get called. Hoping someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/a3OL5XDkRy1Gn4QgTpNC?p=preview

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){ console.log('hi'); }
```

**Edit:** I changed the 'E' to an 'A', saw that mistake, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey pal you need to learn a lot .

Couple of things that i updated

1) Added angular.js in the script tag.

2) Added ng-app="" on the body

3) template->templateUrl (If you need to add HTML file).

4) Don't add html in other templates Angular is SPA(single page application).

HTML:-

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div read-more="">
      <div>This is a test</div>
      <div>This is the complete stuff</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Js:-

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('readMore', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      extraClasses: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log("Hello");
     // element.children()[0].append('<a href="" class="readMoreLink">Read more</a>');
      //element.children()[1].append('<a href="" class="readLessLink">Read less</a>');
    },
    templateUrl: 'readMore.html'
  };
});
```

Here is updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EZqm8KKq5uxwx4kgixKU?p=preview)

Don't worry you will learn about this soon just practice happy coding.
Good tutorials are as follows:-

1) Phonecat simple app [Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

2) Thinkser.io [Link](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/)